# Why my autoencoder model is not learning?

Tags: keras, conv-neural-network, tensorflow2.0, autoencoder

I'm trying to solve captcha dataset using autoencoder. The [dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/fournierp/captcha-version-2-images) is RGB images.

I converted the RGB images to one channel, i.e.:

[image]

(The shape of the image is (48, 200)).

So what I did next, is to use take the text of the captcha (in our case "emwpn"), and create another image, with same shape(48, 200) with this text, i.e.:

[image]

And what I tried is to feed the encoder of the autoencoder with captchas, and feed the decoder with images I created.

I didn't know if this method will be good, but I didn't expect it not to learn anything. When I tried to predict the test dataset, all I got was purple images, i.e.:

```
capchas_array_test_pred = conv_ae.predict(capchas_array_test)
plt.imshow(capchas_array_test_pred[1])
```

[image]

This means that the autoencoder predicts 0 for all the pixels of all the images.

This is the code for the conv autoencoder:

```
def rounded_accuracy(y_true, y_pred):
    return keras.metrics.binary_accuracy(tf.round(y_true), tf.round(y_pred))

conv_encoder = keras.models.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Reshape([48, 200, 1], input_shape=[48, 200]),
    keras.layers.Conv2D(16, kernel_size=5, padding="SAME"),
    keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
    keras.layers.Activation("relu"),
    keras.layers.Conv2D(32, kernel_size=5, padding="SAME", activation="selu"),
    keras.layers.Conv2D(64, kernel_size=5, padding="SAME", activation="selu"),
    keras.layers.AvgPool2D(pool_size=2),
])
conv_decoder = keras.models.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(32, kernel_size=5, strides=2, padding="SAME", activation="selu",
                                input_shape=[6, 25, 64]),
    keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(16, kernel_size=5, strides=1, padding="SAME", activation="selu"),
    keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(1, kernel_size=5, strides=1, padding="SAME", activation="sigmoid"),
    keras.layers.Reshape([48, 200])
])

conv_ae = keras.models.Sequential([conv_encoder, conv_decoder])
conv_ae.compile(loss="mse", optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=1e-1), metrics=[rounded_accuracy])
history = conv_ae.fit(capchas_array_train, capchas_array_rewritten_train, epochs=20,
                      validation_data=(capchas_array_valid, capchas_array_rewritten_valid))
```

The model didn't learn anything:

```
Epoch 2/20
24/24 [==============================] - 1s 53ms/step - loss: 60879.9883 - rounded_accuracy: 0.0637 - val_loss: 60930.7344 - val_rounded_accuracy: 0.0635
Epoch 3/20
24/24 [==============================] - 1s 53ms/step - loss: 60878.5781 - rounded_accuracy: 0.0637 - val_loss: 60930.7344 - val_rounded_accuracy: 0.0635
Epoch 4/20
24/24 [==============================] - 1s 53ms/step - loss: 60879.2656 - rounded_accuracy: 0.0637 - val_loss: 60930.7344 - val_rounded_accuracy: 0.0635
Epoch 5/20
24/24 [==============================] - 1s 53ms/step - loss: 60876.4648 - rounded_accuracy: 0.0637 - val_loss: 60930.7344 - val_rounded_accuracy: 0.0635
Epoch 6/20
24/24 [==============================] - 1s 53ms/step - loss: 60878.4883 - rounded_accuracy: 0.0637 - val_loss: 60930.7344 - val_rounded_accuracy: 0.0635
Epoch 7/20
24/24 [==============================] - 1s 53ms/step - loss: 60880.8242 - rounded_accuracy: 0.0637 - val_loss: 60930.7344 - val_rounded_accuracy: 0.0635
```

I tried to check what the check what happens if I feed the encoder and the decoder with the same images:

```
conv_ae.compile(loss="mse", optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=1e-1), metrics=[rounded_accuracy])
history = conv_ae.fit(capchas_array_train, capchas_array_train, epochs=20,
                      validation_data=(capchas_array_valid, capchas_array_valid))
```

And again I got purple images:

[image]

P.s. If you interested, this is the notebook:
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1gA1XN1NOZKylGDhVu4PKXWhrPU4q9Ady

---

EDIT-

This is the preprocessing I did to the images:

```
1. Convert RGB image to one channel.
2. Normalize the image from value from 0 to 255 for each pixel, to 0 to 1.
3. Resize the (50, 200) image to (48, 200) - for simpler pooling in the autoencoder (48 can be divided by 2 more times, and stay integer, than 50)
```

This is the function for the preprocessing 1,2 steps:

```
def rgb2gray(rgb):
    r, g, b = rgb[:,:,0], rgb[:,:,1], rgb[:,:,2]
    gray = (0.2989 * r + 0.5870 * g + 0.1140 * b)

    for x in range(rgb.shape[1]):
      for y in range(rgb.shape[0]):
        if gray[y][x]>128:
          gray[y][x] = 1.0
        else:
          gray[y][x] = 0.0
    return gray
```

Comment: The text is not in the same location, you should probably standardize that.

Comment: Your decoder is lacking downsampling between the Conv2d layers, is that intentional?

Comment: I would try first with a model with only the reshapes, to check that the learning is correctly setup. And then add a single Conv2d layer

Comment: @jonnor Yeah this is why I didn't expect it to work good, but at least do something. The encoder is also upsample the filters.

Comment: @jonnor Just tried only reshapes, and this give the same image as input.

Comment: Ok then just add layers, test again. Etc until you have built a model

Comment: What preprocessing operations have you done on the images? Include them in your question.

Comment: Normalize all the images by dividing the pixel values by 255.0.

Comment: @today I normalized the images - that the background would be "1"s and the captcha would be "0"s, and this didn't change the result. I will add to the question the preprocessing steps.

Comment: @jonnor I added more layer to the encoder and the decoder, this improved the val_rounded_accuracy to 0.2071 (from 0.06) in epoch 1, but it didn't learn anything (kept getting same accuracy in all epoches). Plus I don't think num of layers is the problem. It's not like the model is learning slow, it just doesn't learn anything - at all.

Comment: Reduce the learning rate. It is possible to saturate in the first epoch.

Comment: @jonnor I tried many learning rates, none of them made them algo learn (smallest I tried is 1e-3)

Answer (score 1):

1. Your architecture doesn't have any sense. If you want to create an autoencoder you need to understand that you're going to reverse process after encoding. That means that if you have three convolutional layers with filters in this order: 64, 32, 16; You should make the next group of convolutional layers to do the inverse: 16, 32, 64. That's the reason of why your algorithm is not learning.
2. You won't get the result that you have expected. You will get a similar structure of that kind of captcha but you won't that clearly text output. If you want that, you need another kind of algorithm (one that allows you to do character segmentation).

Comment: As far as I know, the decoder is the reverse process of the encoder in my code. The decoder gets image of the shape [6, 25, 64] (image size is (6, 25) with 64 filters), then the num of filters go to 32, 16, then to 1.

Comment: If you have solution, please show me what to fix in my code.